# Where is that house with amazing lakeview from HBO's Band Of Brothers?

Tags: film-location, band-of-brothers

Is it a private property if not can you visit to look at the view?

[image]

[The house with the view I'm talking about]

Comment: This is trivia that could have easily been found by checking IMDb: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185906/locations .

Answer (score 4):

It's a real place.

It's the [**Giessbach Hotel**](http://www.giessbach.ch/en/home.html) in  Brienz, Switzerland

[image]

...and yes, you can stay there.

[image]

Comment: Wow! I bet that was a rough week's filming for the cast & crew... I mean, where would they stay whilst they were shooting in such an inhospitable location? :P

Comment: Probably not there...it only has 70 rooms and they're expensive as you can imagine. Plus they would have filmed in the closed season.

Comment: I was joking really, but I bet some of them stayed there - the majority of the crew would be in some local hostelry though... cheap & [not so] cheerful - e.g. https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@46.7544722,8.0292517,3a,75y,133.68h,82.47t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sGcl-s2inlPAD3k2pCRR6gQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1